# PhpStorm 2022.2.2 Laravel Model Relationships and Attributes recognised as magic methods

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, phpdoc

How can I declare my model relationships and custom attributes properly so that they will be available from auto-completion and have the warning "property accessed via magic method" disappear?

I have nothing above my Model class and I've tried a few examples but none seems to work. i.e `@method`, `@param` or I just can't figure out the proper syntax for it.

`quantity_remaining` is a custom attribute for my Model.

I have it like this ATM:

```php
class MyModel extends Model
{

    /**
     * @return HasOne
     */
     public function packages(): HasOne{
          return $this->hasOne(Package::class, 'related_id', 'related_id');
     }

     public function getQuantityRemainingAttribute(): Int{
            //more codes here but not needed for this example
    
            return 1;
        }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You might want to define [properties](https://pear.php.net/reference/PhpDocumentor-latest/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html) in the class doc block. I renamed the `packages` relationship to `package`, because it is a hasOne relationship.

```
/**
* @property Package $packages
* @property int quantity_remaining
*/

class MyModel extends Model
{
     public function package(): HasOne{
        return $this->hasOne(Package::class, 'related_id', 'related_id');
     }

     public function getQuantityRemainingAttribute(): Int{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a new warning after adding them. "Potential polymorphic call" is there a way to just ignore this? i.e remove the warning? since the attributes will always return a value when called and I don't want to surround it with an if check. thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You will need to define fields in model class like:

```
public mixed $name;
public mixed $surname;
public mixed $email;
public mixed $password;
```

while your fillables are:

```
protected $fillables = ['name', 'surname', 'email', 'password'];
```

Comment: In fact you should not explicitly define your model's properties. It will break much of the laravel _magic_